# Identification requests for (quasi) military insignia

Tags: discussion

A [recent question asking for an "armed forces" cap-badge to be identified](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/13864/7879) makes me wonder about the boundaries for on-topic questions here?

The question was simply asking for identification, it didn't seem to be asking about possible political ramifications.

How can I tell whether identifying a military insignia is on-topic here?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that we've made a decision about this one way or the other.

This is the kind of question that should be on-topic somewhere, as it is narrow and answerable.  Among current stacks, it probably makes the most sense here.

In the future, we might have to bound it with additional rules, e.g. only current insignia, image must be included, etc.

I would vote for making these questions on-topic.  At least until we find reasons to bound it further than the two rules I proposed.

Comment: I would agree with those two rules.  If it's not a current insignia, it clearly would belong to [History.SE], but for something brand new, this is probably the best spot.